# Terrible performance on new laptop

Tags: windows-10, performance

I purchased laptop a few months back: Lenovo Ideapad 520 - 8th Gen Core i7 QuadCore 20GB 1TB 4-GB Nvidia MX150.

- Windows 10 Pro (fully updated).
- No Anti-Virus.
- Some light development tools.
- No servers.

After using it for a few days, I immediately noticed unbelievably bad performance during startup which took up to 15 minutes. The HDD light would stay on constantly for hours even when simple applications were running such as MS Word, VLC, etc.

I reinstalled Windows multiple times in vain. I even had the vendor replace the hard drive with a brand new one. Same results.

The Task Manager shows 100% utilization of HDD activity but the individual processes consumption does not add to 100%.

Not sure how to diagnose this and any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I am going to guess you have Windows 10 version 1903 installed.  Edit your question to include that vital information

Comment: It sounds like your hard drive may be bad. You should run the built in hardware diagnostics.

Comment: Brand new? Then Cortana (Search) may be rebuilding. Just for comparison, try running a Linux distro (e.g.Ubuntu) from USB or dual-boot, to see if it's hardware or Windows that's the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download and install Windows 10 v1809 and don't update it(download drivers from lenovo site if required).
Open the following link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Then on the page there is no option to download v1809 so in chrome right click on the page and click "Inspect", In the inspect window click on the three dotted menu in the top right corner

> click "More tools"
>
> Click "Network Conditions"
>
> Under "User Agent" uncheck "Select Automatically"
>
> From the dropdown select "Android 4.0.2 Browser" and refresh the page.
>
> Scroll down and under "Select Edition" Choose "Windows 10 October 2018 Update"